# Extract multiple lines string after a variable match in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to extract the multiple lines in curly braces after matching a string "noon"

> file : exp.tcl

```
if { $time == "noon"} {

ready for lunch.

whats for food? {asian, korean}

going cafe or out?

}
```

I stored the file in an array and reading it with foreach loop to perform other regex function. I am trying with `extract_multiple` but unable to get return string.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Answer (score 3):

## Foreward

This type of pattern matching is fraught with edge cases. But if your input string is as basic as you're sample text then you should be ok.

## Description

```regex
^.*?"noon".*?\{([\s\S]*?)^\}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Note this expression uses the multiline option which causes the `^` to match the start of each line.

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/vT9hM8/2

**Sample text**

```
if { $time == "noon"} {

ready for lunch.

whats for food? {asian, korean}

going cafe or out?

}
```

**Sample Matches**

Capture group 1 will have:

```
ready for lunch.

whats for food? {asian, korean}

going cafe or out?
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  "noon"                   '"noon"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \{                       '{'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s\S]*?                 any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), non-whitespace (all
                             but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \}                       '}'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Ther's no need to use the ugly `[\s\S]` in Perl. Just `.` with the `/s` modifier is fine. I also see no point in `^.*?` at the beginning in any language

Comment: I'm using `\s\S` because I'm also using the `m` flag which allows me to use the `^` symbol to match the beginning of each line. If you remove one of the character classes then perl will not match new line characters. The point of having the `^.*?` is so that all lines are captured. not just from the word `noon` till the closing `}`. This offers the programmer the flexibility of having the text from all lines so they can do additional processing if desired.

Comment: I don't follow. There's nothing wrong with using the`/m` and `/s` modifiers in combination

Comment: When using the `m` flag, can you tell me how the `^` near the end of the expression would behave?

Comment: `^` always matches at the beginning of the string. With the `/m` modifier in place it also matches before any character that immediately follows a newline character

Comment: It sounds like you're lamenting the aesthetics of a working expression. Where as https://regex101.com/r/cR7bQ5/1 shows that changing the `[\s\S]` to `.` and using the `/s` option does not yield the same results as https://regex101.com/r/vT9hM8/2.

Comment: That exactly what I'm doing. There is a lot more to writing a good computer program than making "something that works". It's also a *very* bad idea to have more than one quantifier with a non-greedy modifier, as it is highly likely that they combine to produce *catastrophic backtracking*

Comment: Can you produce sample text that would cause the claimed catastrophic backtracking? I contend that making something that works trumps aesthetics everytime, unless it's art. In other words a beautiful chunk of code that does not do perform as desired is worse than one that works.

Comment: I made the point mainly as a general one. (You should take a look at [*Runaway Regular Expressions: Catastrophic Backtracking*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)
and read the last section called *Quickly Matching a Complete HTML File*.) It doesn't apply so much here because you are using unmodified dots, so the first two non-greedy matches `.*?` can only ever be one line in length.

Comment: In fact they are superfluous here and all you need is `.*` except for the last `.*?`. This works fine and I find it much more readable `/ ^ (?= .* "noon" ) .* \{ (?s: .*? ) ^ \} /mgx`. The `?s` temporarily applies the `/s` modifier for just the enclosing parentheses. The thing is that a nice-looking piece of code tends to be clearer, and clearer code reduces the chance of bugs. A messy chunk of code that *appears* to work may contain hidden bugs that you haven't found yet, and will be more difficult to find even after the symptoms have been encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is far from clear, which is why I've held back from posting an answer until now

I wouldn't use a regex for this, except to check whether a line contained the string `"noon"`. There's also no need to read your file into an array

This one-liner prints all lines starting with one containing `"noon"` and ending with one that starts with a closing brace `}`

If you want something different, like matching nested braces, then you must clarify your question

```
$ perl -ne '/"noon"/ .. /^\}/ and print' exp.tcl
```

#### output

```
if { $time == "noon"} {

ready for lunch.

whats for food? {asian, korean}

going cafe or out?

}
```